# How to get the value from a customer field?

Tags: joomla3.0

Joomla 3.7: I want to use the new customer field in my index.php for header data.

I found, I must start with:

> JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR .
>   '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');

but how can I get the value of a field from a site custom field in my index.php like:

> $value= FieldsHelper::getValue('SiteID', 'FieldID');

Thanks
Bernd

Answer (score 1):

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
print_r(  FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', ['id'=> JFactory::getUser()->id]));
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for custom field in article not user. So get the value from a ArticleID and CustomfieldID.